# Special Characters are coming in logback report, so link for the screenshot is not coming

Tags: java, html, selenium, logging, logback

Logback updated to 1.2.3 and thus HTML reports are not displaying the links. When I looked at the HTML source it seems the link is coming as displayed below

```
<td class="Message">&lt;a href=&quot;com.prahs.tests.pso.masterOPT.cm.TC_265346-verifyContractCreationNov-14-2019 103619-40.html&quot; target=new&gt;verifyContractCreation&lt;/a&gt;</td>
```

How do we get rid off the special characters?

Comment: I think you need to encode the URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters/10786112#10786112

Comment: I tried the approach and it didnt help me

Comment: Okay, after the edit the link looks different.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: You didn't state it in the question so I am asking: are you using the HTMLLayout for logging? Then it is normal that some characters are replaced. See this class where the replacement is done: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/helpers/Transform.java#L55

Comment: But this conversion is happening in logback side. I mean i check the string value which i am sending to logback to create the data and there is no special characters in it, In fact this is happening after the file creation is happening

Comment: Yes, of course. This is what the HTMLLayout is doing. Maybe you should post your logback config.

Comment: it seems its too long to post it here

Comment: Upload it somewhere and post the link?

Comment: https://github.com/vineethin/logback/blob/master/logback.xml

Comment: This should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637032/format-links-in-logback